# Set session-state Cookiemode property for click event?

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I know we can set `UseUri` Property of session state in Web.config but
but what if I want to set it on click event or `Page_Load`?

I did the following but it didn't work:

```
protected void cmdLinkAbsolute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool b = Session.CookieMode == HttpCookieMode.UseUri;
        b = true;  
    }
```

The application use Deafult "UseCookie" mode.

How can we set this session property in click event?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you are up to?

Comment: yes. I want to track session state for two relative links in the same page so when user click on the first link he redirect to the new page through cookie

Comment: and for the second page, i want to use modified URL (QueryString)

Comment: What is the role of a cookie in that scenario? I did not get it actually. If you want to redirect some of the specific URLs to somewhere else you may want to check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: I know how to redirect, I want session ID to be transferred to the new page through cookie when someone clicks on the first relative link and through QueryString when they click on the second link. I don't know if I could convey what i meant